# What is the word for a man who keeps returning for other people to abuse him?

Tags: epithet-requests

I'm looking for a word describing a man who keeps returning to a place although people there always abuse him and say bad things to him. He keeps going back because maybe he likes to experience this like a Howling Mad Murdock of the A TEAM.

Comment: If he enjoys it, then your characterization of it as abuse is off the mark.

Comment: Politician? ...

Comment: When are we going to get some more questions, Mr Beefer?

Comment: Just in case others are misled: this is a joke/troll account that asks silly and deliberately disingenuous questions that nonetheless require a bit of lateral thinking to locate the actual jokes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*glutton for punishment* is fairly popular

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+glutton+for+punishment

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glutton_for_punishment

Comment: 'Glutton for punishment' doesn't imply he enjoys it or gets something out of it. You can be a glutton for punishment, and hate doing what you're doing because for example, you're trying to get ahead in a job. You still do it, not because you like the treatment you get, but because you've got your eye on a bigger prize. The OP's example refers to someone with a pathology, which is why 'masochist' works better.

Comment: depending on which definition you follow, it does. Either way, it doesn't imply that the person *does not* enjoy it.

Comment: Yes, you're right Joseph Neathawk: the OP looks like he might be getting something out of it.

Answer (score 8):

You are probably referring to a case of [masochism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/masochism):

> gratification gained from pain, deprivation, degradation, etc., inflicted or imposed on oneself, either as a result of one's own actions or the actions of others, especially the tendency to seek this form of gratification.

[masochist](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/masochist?s=t):

> a person who is gratified by pain, degradation, etc., that is self-imposed or imposed by others.

Source: http://dictionary.reference.com

Answer (score 2):

I think masochist fits in the respect that the subject is deriving some sort of pleasure from the deprecation, but based on that he keeps returning to that situation as if he is connected to it, the term *dependent* comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard the word "doormat" used to describe such people.